# C# Name convention for type names of same kind

Tags: c#, naming-conventions

Sorry, I don't have a better title.

I have naming convention question which is a bit difficult to describe.

I have the following lib projects:

```
Common.CQRS
-- Interfaces
---- IQuery
Common.CQRS.EntityFramework
-- Interfaces
---- IQuery <--- Question
Common.CQRS.Mongo
-- Interfaces
---- IQuery <--- Question
```

Obviously IQuery does everywhere the same thing, just related (in this case) to the data store system.
IQuery from "Common.CQRS" is the base and the other IQuery have to inherit this IQuery.
In the past I would name IQuery from "Common.CQRS" IQueryBase, but I read that this should be avoided.
I could name IQuery from "Common.CQRS.EntityFramework" IEntityFrameworkQuery and for Mongo IMongoQuery and so on, should I?
It's somehow redundant because of the namespace, isn't it?

Thanks for you opinion.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you've suggested changing it to is okay.  I have your current convention in one project I work on, and the proposed one in the other.  It makes the code nicer to look at.  Having to specify `EntityFramework.Interfaces.IQuery` or `Mongo.Interfaces.IQuery` in your code everywhere is ugly.  `IEntityFrameworkQuery` and `IMongoQuery` are much nicer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working in a team, whole team should agree and stick to one convention.

If you are an individual developer/ sole decision maker, then this question makes sense here, because many people, many conventions and practices they follow.

`IQueryBase` - You can have this or preferably `IBaseQuery` only if you think there's not going to be an implementation (`class`) that implements only this interface. Otherwise better to keep it as `IQuery`.

`namespace.IQuery` - I agree with @Brendan that `EntityFramework.Interfaces.IQuery` etc looks ugly. However you can shorten it using namespace alias.

```
using efi = Common.CQRS.EntityFramework.Interfaces;
using mi = Common.CQRS.Mongo.Interfaces;

efi.IQuery
mi.IQuery
```

That's shorter but not readable as to what `efi` and `mi` stand for. I just mentioned it as a possibility to shorten references. If you don't like fully qualified names or namespace alias, then you are going to run into ambiguity error.

`ISpecializedQuery` - So this is the only option left and better of all. Agreed that `EntityFramework.Interfaces.IEntityFrameworkQuery` is redundant but naming standards are more for code readability.